# Anonymous module using typescript

Tags: javascript, module, typescript

Is there anything like anonymous module in Typescript that would translate into the following?

```
(function(){  })()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an alternative to do this, but you can still use exactly that syntax inside a TypeScript file to scope your contents using an immediately executing function.

```
(function(){  
    var myClass = new SomeModule.SomeClass();
})();
```

I would expect to see this quite often in the `app.ts` file.

If you really want to get some TypeScript in there, you could shorten it to:

```
() => {
    var x = 1;
}();
```

Comment: Nice use of Lambda style there! +1

Comment: Your solution does not allow to add class into the "anonymous module". I guess there is no way to have scoping with classes inside, right?